# Setting contentInset of WKWebView scrollView causes page jump to top

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, wkwebview

After setting `contentInset` of `WKWebView`, I found if I use default swipe gesture to navigate between pages, `WKWebView` will not reserve the `contentInset` and just **jump** to the top, does anyone know how to resolve that? Thanks!

[image]

My sample code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
        let view = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        view.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        view.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        view.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        view.navigationDelegate = self
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.view.addSubview(self.webView)

        if let url = URL(string: "http://www.wikipedia.org") {
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set contentInset for a scrollview of WKWebView, you need set another property of WKWebview with same value.
**view.setValue(UIEdgeInsets, forKey: "_obscuredInsets")**

Refer to : https://opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit2/WebKit2-7600.1.4.11.10/ChangeLog

```
private lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
        let view = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        view.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        view.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        let edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        view.setValue(edgeInsets, forKey: "_obscuredInsets")
        view.scrollView.contentInset = edgeInsets
        return view
    }()
```

If you set contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic, there will have a extra edge of status bar. You also need to add the status bar height to obscuredInsets.

```
view.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = . automatic
webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
webView.setValue(UIEdgeInsets(top: 50 + 44, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), forKey: "_obscuredInsets")
```

**44 is the height of status bar(safeArea).**

---

Checked the newest WKWebView: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKWebView.mm

Now need add an extra property: _haveSetObscuredInsets

**webView.setValue(true, forKey: "_haveSetObscuredInsets")**

Comment: Asesome! Save my day!

Comment: this is missing `webView.setValue(true, forKey: "_haveSetObscuredInsets")`